# Web link to download with Android phone?

Tags: android, download, hyperlink

In my web site i make link like`<a href="test.txt">DOWNLOAD</a>`. And when i open this site on my Android phone and click on link, standart browser opens txt file. I want to download file and not open.

What i may to do for that?

Thanks!

Comment: what it has to do with programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set MIME type set on your server setting.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the text.txt is linked with a viewer hence if will download and open.

Secondly, it would be stored in downloads folder on your sdcard.